# Switching between two styles for the same component

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-template, angular6

I'm trying to include two style URLS in my angular app ,

I tried several other similar questions, but the answers are not working for me.I don't know how to fix.

What I want to achieve is to switch between two styles based on if condition

Why I want to do that : it's because the app should support two languages which requires RTL and LTR style files for the same component ,,

Is it possible to handle such an issue??

Answer (score 0):

specify some function for [class] in .html

```
<span [class]="getStyleClass()">ABCD</span>
```

and then add somelogic to your getStyleClass() in your .ts

```
getStyleClass() {
    return this.value > this.anotherValue?"classOne":"classTwo";
  }
```

Comment: thanks a lot ,,
but this is for one element is it possible to change the whole style URL cause the whole style shall change based on a property value

Comment: Then you can try to add stylesheet dynamically like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496999/angular-2-how-do-i-conditionally-add-styles-to-my-component

Comment: tried to add the style as it said this is what i got

Comment: Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/nav.component.scss' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: this is what i added in the ts file 

 addStyleSheet() {
    var headID = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
    link.id = 'widget_styles';
    headID.appendChild(link);

    link.href = 'nav.component.scss';
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addStyleSheet()
  }

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 css files : src/assets/**style1.css** and src/assets/**style2.css**

> **Step - 1** : **Add** a link with an id inside head of **index.html** file

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="" id="mycss" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-app></my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

> **Step - 2** : Use following **typescript** and modify with your own desired logic

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
 import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  files = ["assets/style1.css","assets/style2.css"]

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) {}

  toggle() {

    var oldlink = this.document.getElementById("mycss");

    var newlink = this.document.createElement("link");
    newlink.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    newlink.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    newlink.setAttribute("href", this.files[1]);

    this.document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).replaceChild(newlink, oldlink);
  }
}
```