# condition for load styleUrls in component angular

Tags: angular

I want use of multi css in styleUrls

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [condition 'if' for Which load css]
})
```

i tired

Comment: Try to look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496999/angular-2-how-do-i-conditionally-add-styles-to-my-component this link

Answer (score 2):

You can use a ternary operator inside:

```
const url1 = './foo.css';
const url2 = './bar.css';

let condition = true

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [condition ? url1 : url2]
})
```

Comment: Please add description to your answer instead of posting code only

Answer (score 0):

You can write a ternary operator inline:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [condition ? 'someFile.css' : 'someOtherFile.css']
})
```

Comment: can the condition be a boolean @input field in the component? can I use a function of the component class instead of the array for styleUrls ?

Comment: No, it can't, as that property is defined even before the class exists, and way before the component is instantiated. If you wan't to change the style based on the state of the component, I would apply differents classes based on the state.

Comment: actually i'm going to play with component class inheritance & give the inheritor a simple decoration that only changes the selector (tough I wonder how the selector is matched if multiple components could satisfy it eg `x-button` vs`x-button.red`) and its own style url